# Can I use svn copy to copy a template folder?

Tags: svn

Would the scenario below be an usage of svn copy? If not, what would I just.

Repository1 will have a template folder with svn externals to other folders from another repository.

If a user wants to use that template folder they will perform a svn copy on the template folder to their repository (Repository2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot copy (you really mean de-reference) folders between repositories.
What will happen is that you just copy the folder with the external definition.
However you are still pointing into the origin repository.

You cannot copy anything between repositories (except file-copy, without history)

Comment: Yes, I believe that is what I want. I basically want to duplicate that template folder to another repository.

Comment: as long as changes inside externals will still be pointing to their respective repositories, not the repository of the checked out folder